# Why can't i see the latest DAG's run in the UI?

Tags: python, airflow

Whatever DAG i did, it's last work in the UI will be visible only after the next run has finished.
At the same time, i'm sure that it completed and worked correctly.

For example. The last run in the UI was at 8:58. In fact, the last run was at 8:59 and it will appear in the UI only after the end of the next dag.

What could be the problem?

I just started working with Airflow a few month ago, i may not understand something.

Here is a picture from the DAGs page, the last run time was 8:58.

[image]

Next picture shows that after 8:58 4 tasks were completed, 2 of them were completed after 8:59, which indicates that the last run for some reason is not displayed on the page with all dags, as well as in the Tree view. The dag entry will only appear on the next run.

[image]

[image]

There is DAG code

```
import sys
import os
from airflow.models import BaseOperator
import datetime
import cx_Oracle
from airflow.operators.python import PythonOperator
from airflow.providers.oracle.operators.oracle import OracleOperator
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.providers.microsoft.mssql.operators.mssql import MsSqlOperator

default_args = {
        'owner': 'airflow',
        'depends_on_past': True,
        'trigger_rule': 'all_success',
        'start_date': datetime.datetime(2023, 5, 25)
        }

def script1():
    connection = cx_Oracle.connect('Username', 'Password', 'Link')
    cur = connection.cursor()

def script2():
    connection_ibm = cx_Oracle.connect('Username', 'Password', 'Link')
    cur_ibm = connection_ibm.cursor()

with DAG(
        dag_id='Check_days',
        schedule_interval='* 5 * * 2,4,6',
        catchup = False,
        default_args = default_args
        ) as dag:
    t1 = PythonOperator(
            task_id = 'script1',
            depends_on_past = True,
            python_callable = script1,
            dag = dag
            )
    t2 = PythonOperator(
            task_id = 'script2',
            depends_on_past = True,
            python_callable = script2,
            dag = dag
            )

t1>>t2
```

Comment: Hello. Could you explain what mean `last run`? `logical date`? by the way could you attach a screen?

Comment: Hello. Sorry, i described the problem not correctly. I mean the last scheduled run. Unfortunately i can't take screenshots on my work system.

Comment: @IlyaVelichko how do you understand that last run was at `8:59`?

Comment: @IlyaVelichko you can attach the output of `airflow dags list-runs -d {DAG_ID_HERE}`  + DAG source

Comment: @DanilaGanchar i edited post and added something, please take a look.

Comment: @IlyaVelichko are you sure that you removed the `success` state from the filters?(`Search` dropdown)

Comment: @DanilaGanchar yes. There only one filter (DAG Id).

Comment: @IlyaVelichko tried to reproduce(`v2.6.1`). unsuccessfully (((. 1 `dag run`, 2 `success tasks`

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Thanks for trying to help me. Pretty strange situation. Appeared recently. By the way, if I trigger dag manually, then it displays correctly.

Comment: @IlyaVelichko what version and scheduler?

Comment: @DanilaGanchar Airflow version 2.0.1. What do you mean by schduler?

Comment: try to upgrade airflow to `2.6`. maybe this will solve the problem. about scheduler... sorry - I mean `executor`(`CeleryExecutor`, `KubernetesExecutor` etc).

Comment: Also use python-oracledb instead of the older cx_Oracle, if possible. See the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a).